# module alias cannot resolve for jest (CRA and customize-cra)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I create a react app with CRA and add `react-app-rewired`and `TypeScript`
I map some modules in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@constants/*": ["constants/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@grid/*": ["components/Grid/*"],
      "@grid-share/*": ["components/Grid/Share/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["util/*"],
      "@services/*": ["Services/*"]
    }
  },
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json"
}
```

and also define them as alias modules in `config-overrides.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const { override,  addBabelPlugins } = require('customize-cra');   
module.exports = override(
  ...addBabelPlugins(
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ["./src"],
        alias: {
          "@constants": "./src/constants",
          "@components": "./src/components",
          "@grid": "./src/components/grid",
          "@utils": "./src/util",
          "@services": "./src/Services",
          "@grid-share": "./src/components/Grid/Share"
        }
      }
    ],
  ),
);
```

everything is okey for `yarn start` but for `yarn test`, it cannot resolve the defined modules. what should I do for resolving the alias module for `jest`?

Comment: have you tried setting `NODE_PATH=src` instead of using aliases?

Comment: I using typescript when I adding NODE_PATH in .env it shows a warning which refers it is deprecated

Comment: I'll just friendly point out that you don't need react-app-rewired for that, CRA supports it; and also rewired brings a LOT of headaches when updating CRA to newer versions.

Here's the link: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/importing-a-component#absolute-imports

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: actually it is out of my hand.the application is implemented and the company both an Admin UI template which force us to us the rewired

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okey, I found the answer.  we need to define same module alias in package.json

```
 "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@constants/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/constants/$1",
      "@utils/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/util/$1",
      "@grid-share/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/components/Grid/Share/$1",
      "@grid/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/components/Grid/$1"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Didn't work, when I put the same configuration in the jest.config.js file